# Qt: Convert QString to Hexadecimal

Tags: c++, qt

I know this is a very basic question but I'm newbie in Qt and I don't know to do it. I'm trying to convert a QString value (like "AA110011") to hexadecimal. I would like to obtain 0xaa110011. I've tried with this code:

```
QByteArray b = aString.toUtf8();

for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++ )
{
    if ( b[i] >= 65 && b[i] <= 70 )
    {
        b[i] = b[i] - 55;
    }
    else if (b[i] >= 48 && b[i] <= 57)
    {
        b[i] = b[i] - 48;
    }
}
```

I obtain in the Memory at Vairable "[0]" the value 0a 0a 01 01 00 00 01 01 and I don't know how could I obtain aa 11 00 11.

Could you help me? thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `int QString::toInt(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const`?

Comment: ``int value = QString("AA110011").toInt(NULL, 16);`` in addition to mah. If you need it as "char*" just typecast: 
``char c[4-i] = (char) ((value >> i*8) & 0xFF)``

Answer (score 10):

Try [QString::toInt](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qstring.html#toInt), [QString::toUInt](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qstring.html#toUInt), [QString::toLong](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qstring.html#toLong) etc., for example:

```
const QString str = QLatin1String("AA110011");
bool ok;
const unsigned int parsedValue = str.toUInt(&ok, 16);
if (!ok) {
    //Parsing failed, handle error here
}

qDebug() << parsedValue;
```

The second argument is the base, 16 in this case for hexadecimal.

This solution will work if your string fits into a unsigned long long or shorter - it will not work if you want to convert arbitrarily long strings that way.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have a QString you can do the following

```
QString res = string.toAscii().toHex();
qDebug() << res;
```

[reference](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-18719.html)

Comment: That returns the hex value of the ASCII encoded string contents, not the number.

Comment: In what form u want a number ?? You can convert a number to string by using setNum(decimalNumber ,16) method and similarly you can obtain any base in the form of string but there is no separate datatype for hexadecimal in QT as far I know

Answer (score 3):

```
 QString prgName = query.value(1).toString();
 prgName.toLatin1().toHex();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [QByteArray::fromHex()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex)

```
QByteArray a = QByteArray::fromHex(s.toLatin1())
qDebug() << a;
```